# bash: extract double from string

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, string, parsing

I have this string in bash:

```
str=sdk.iphoneos4.1.sdk
```

and I would like to have a variable with '4.1' in it

is there any way to parse a float/double value in bash ?

Comment: As in, extract the 4.1 from the above string? If so, you should be able to do it with `grep`, although I'm not experienced with it. One of the grep gurus here will be able to help you out though!

Comment: A version number is a list of ints, not a float. For example, 4.1 and 4.001 are usually considered equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash 3.2 or greater:

```
str=sdk.iphoneos4.1.sdk
pattern='[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
[[ $str =~ $pattern ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the surrounding text always stays the same:

```
str=${str#sdk.iphoneos}
str=${str%.sdk}
```

---

This is less portable (`bash` only), but accepts anything in place of `iphoneos`:

```
shopt -s extglob
str=${str##sdk.*([a-z])}
str=${str%.sdk}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming no other digits elsewhere

```
$ str=sdk.iphoneos4.0.0.1.sdk
$ echo $str | grep -Po '(\d+.*\d+)(?=\.)'
4.0.0.1
```